# AWS IAM user policy to restrict access to specific folder (EBS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

Could you please help with the following: is there a possibility to restrict access for some IAM user groups to specific folder in AWS EC2 (with storage located on EBS)?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

No can't do. AWS has no visibility inside your EC2. You can do that for S3 buckets/directories in S3 bucket or files in S3 bucket.

Comment: As far as I understood, S3 is a type of storage as well as EBS? Can I use S3 with EC2 the same way as I use EBS with it? (mount to EC2 and run Python?) Thank you very much!

Comment: They are both type of storage but different in nature. S3 is Object Storage (think of it as google drive space) while EBS is a Block Storage (think of it as hard disk on your computer). You can mount S3 bucket on EC2 but it is not officially supported plus it will still not be able to do what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot achieve that with IAM permissions; even if you find an over engineered way to somehow implement it - it'll be a hack and not a something IAM permissions are designed for. BTW what is the exact use case? what is the OS? why don't you want to use OS based file system solutions for that? if the user interpolation is the reason then why not perform AD-join and use OS based file-system restrictions? that-way your solutions will be more robust, scalable, sensible and elegant.